# macOS High Sierra - Time Machine no longer recognizing iMac backups on USB drive

Tags: time-machine

My iMac backups that are stored on an external USB drive are suddenly not being recognized for backing up. Using <kbd>option</kbd> key and pull-down menu, I can select the set of backups on this USB drive and can restore from them, but I cannot get Time Machine to use that folder for more incremental backups — It wants to create a brand new backup (for which there is not room).

I have deleted the file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist` and rebooted the iMac, but the problem persists. I think the cause may be related to my very brief use of this USB backup file with Migration Assistant to put files onto an external hard drive: that drive now seems to be linked to this backup file in the `Backups.backupdp` folder.

How do I change that? I have discussed this at length with Apple support but was given no really useful advice.

Comment: Have you recently upgraded to High Sierra? Have these issues begun since then? Are you using the new Apple File System in High Sierra, or are you using the older file system?

Comment: Further comment: It looks like this problem could be solved using the utility tmutil.

Comment: After I upgraded to High Sierra I continued to do automated incremental backups to this drive. I am using 10.13.4 from the start of my upgrade. I can extract backups from the file but I cannot incrementally add to it. The apple unit utility tmutil is intended to deal with exactly this problem of realigning backup assignments, but I am not able to get it to do this

Comment: When you upgraded to High Sierra, did you also upgrade the file system to `APFS`?

Comment: I just ran the installation of High Sierra, using a downloaded installer from Apple. Whatever the installer did was done. I did not take any action to reformat any of my hard drives

Comment: Let's check to be sure: Apple Icon->About This Mac->System Report->Hardware->Storage. What does it say for the Macintosh HD volume name under "File System"? If it's APFS, then you've changed filesystems during the upgrade. If it's not, then you still have whatever legacy filesystem you had under Sierra. All of this is to say that I recall reading something that suggested issues with Time Machine across filesystem boundaries. Personally, I went for APFS because I've felt the pain of trying to delete those "sparse bundles".

Comment: The iMac is File System: Journaled HFS+
  Writable: Yes

Comment: The iMac is 
 File System: Journaled HFS+
  Writable: Yes
  Ignore Ownership: No
  Protocol: SATA
  Internal: Yes
  Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)
  S.M.A.R.T. Status: Verified
 The backup external USB drive is, in part
  File System: Journaled HFS+
  Writable: Yes
  Protocol: USB
  Internal: No
  Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)

Comment: OK, well that's not the issue then. Apple's desire to be the computer "for the rest of us" at times leads them to obfuscate things that confound even "all of them". You've taken the logical and correct steps so far, but it seems that this issue goes deeper. I've never encountered the problem you're having, and so I am not the "voice of experience" in this case. I will suggest this however: I think that `tmutil` is your friend, and you should start by reading [this how-to guide](https://www.macworld.com/article/3261111/macs/how-to-fix-the-wrong-time-machine-adoption-for-a-drive-swap.html)

Comment: ... and please let us know how you get on. This forum is only noise unless useful solutions are documented :)

Comment: As you say, I had thought tmutil would be the answer. I have read the man page and numerous discussions and have issued, as best I could, various attempts at exactly what others have done with success to deal with exactly my problem, but all I get when I type the command is the unix response telling me the command requires as arguments the names of the two files I am using. It does not recognize those names as being what it wants.

Comment: ... the two files...? Guess I'm confused. Could you share exactly what you've typed in at the command line?

Comment: I should have said "two words" or "two file names"
Here is an example of what I tried:
sudo tmutil associatedisk [-a] “/Volumes/Macintosh HD” "Volumes/4TB Seagate/Backups.backupdb/Bruce’s iMac/2018-05-11-061933/Macintosh HD”
Here is the message that I always got (it is an explanation of what the command 
A local volume mount point and a snapshot volume path are required.

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be very simple. In the command for tmutil I had copied the format and so I typed "[-a]" when I should have typed "-a". The error message always gave me the impression that the addresses were not correct. The proper error message should have said I should not include "[" or "]"

Comment: What command were you using?